# How to merge two column which have same value into one column given they are sharing the similar product id?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Hi and I'm new to Javascript.
I want to merge this two columns into one columns as they are sharing the same product ID together.

my expected result is to display one column. But i confuse to how to add a checking method to check whether they have column with same display values.

[image]

```
<template lang="html">

<v-data-table
:headers="headers"
:items="labels"
:loading="loading"
class="elevation-1"
 >
  <template slot="items" slot-scope="props">
   <tr>
   <td class="text-xs-left"><br>Product ID: {{props.item.product_id}}<br>Product Title: 
          {{props.item.title}}<br><br></td>
       <td class="text-xs-left">{{getMergePID(props.item.product_id)}}</td>     
      </tr> 
    </template>
   </v-data-table>
 </template>

<script>
export default {
   data () {
     return {
       loading: false,
       labels: [],
       list1: [],
       headers:[
        { text: this.$translate('product_being_promoted'),value: 
        'product_id',sortable:false },
        { text: this.$translate('name'),value: 'shop_name',sortable: false 
                }    
      ],
    }
  },
  mounted(){
   this.getProductPromoteReport();
  },
  methods: {
   getProductPromoteReport(){
   var self = this;
   this.loading = true
   axios.get("/api/merchant/live/getProductPromoteReport")
        .then(response => {
           self.labels = response.data.labels
           this.getPID(this.labels)
           this.loading = false
     })
    },
   getPID(pid){
   this.list1.length = 0
   for(var i = 0; i < pid.length; i++){
    this.list1.push([pid[i].product_id,pid[i].shop_name])
   }
 },
getMergePID(product_id){
   var temp = [];
   this.list1.forEach((item) =>
   {
      if(product_id == item[0])
      {
        temp = temp.concat([item[1]]);
      }
     })
     return temp
   },
  }
 </script>
```

How can i merge into one column only??? Anyone could be help me out? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

With the information provided, it is hard to tell where you get the list under column "names",
But assuming you get the "names" as property from labels---

Try to clean your duplicates straight after the axios call

```
...
...
methods: {
   getProductPromoteReport(){
      this.loading = true
      axios.get("/api/merchant/live/getProductPromoteReport")
       .then(response => {
             if(response.data){
             this.labels = this.removeDuplicates(response.data.labels)
             this.loading = false
       })
       .finally(()=>this.loading = false)
    },
    removeDuplicates(labels) {
       if(!labels) return[];
       let uniqueLabels = [];
       labels.forEach((label) => {
           if(uniqueLabels.find((uniqElem)=> uniqElem.product_id== label.product_id) == null){
               uniqueLabels.push(label);
            }
        });
       return uniqueLabels 
     }
   }
```

then you can just loop through the label items

```
<template slot="items" slot-scope="props">
  <tr>
    <td class="text-xs-left"><br>Product ID: {{props.item.product_id}}<br>Product Title: 
      {{props.item.title}}<br><br></td>
      <td class="text-xs-left">{{props.item.names}}</td>     
  </tr> 
 </template>
```

As stated, the part that is not clear is where the "names" come from so I just asume it's called like that hence the {{props.item.names}}